# como transformar multipoint para point?

Tags: geometria-computacional

Não consigo carregar em DB Postgis uma geometria multipoint para uma tabela com geometria point.

Acontece um erro de constraint em relação a definição da coluna de geometria. Não basta alterar a string desta constraint.

```
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geometry_columns CHECK (geometrytype(geometry_columns) = 'POINT'::text OR geometry_columns IS NULL),
```